# Scenario.write on Cucumber Java- HTML Reports

Tags: cucumber-java

Could anyone help me on this issue?

If I use scenario.write, It is not going to a respective step. for example, if
I use scenario.write in @When it is going to next step that is under @Then.

Do you know why this is happening????

Screen shot of my code and report:

[image: Screen shot of the code and report]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Bug in Cucumber.io version whereas info.cukes library is working as expected

Logged defect(#1349)in https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues